# $\mathfrak{B}=((1,2,0)^t ,(2,1,2)^t ,(3,1,1)^t)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. For what prime numbers p is $\mathfrak{B}$ a basis of $\mathbb{F}^3_p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, prime-numbers, finite-fields, real-numbers

I'm not quite sure, but it seems to me that $\mathbb{F}^3_p$ is the finite field in three dimensions with $p$ elements inside it, where $p$ is the prime number(s) we are looking for. A finite field is simply a field with a finite number of elements, the finite number of elements must always be a prime number

So they are asking for which specific prime numbers the set $\mathfrak{B}$ is still a basis. To be a basis, the elements inside the set $\mathfrak{B}$ need to span the entire vector space, that is

$a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 = x$ for any $x$ element in the space

And the base elements need to be linearly independent, that is

$a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 = 0$ implies $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$

In our case $v_1 = (1,2,0)^t$, $v_2 = (2,1,2)^t$ and $v_3 = (3,1,1)^t$

First, is this correct ?

Second, I don't see what to do now. In the exercise before this one, we verified that $\mathfrak{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$

It seems to me that $p$ could be any prime number, because $\mathbb{F}_p^3$ is in three dimensions, and $\mathfrak{B}$ spans all of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Why would $\mathfrak{B}$ only be a basis for some prime numbers and not others, if we know that $\mathfrak{B}$ spans all of $\mathbb{R^3}$ ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: B spans all of R^3 when you are allowed coefficients in R, but over F_p^3 you are only allowed elements of F_p as scalars. You can use the determinant to tell if vectors form a basis

Comment: @latbbltes Thanks for your help ! The determinant of the three basis vectors is 7, so not zero. Does that mean the the prime number needs to be at least 7 so that the number 7 is contained in the field ? In other words the value of the determinant needs to be allowed in the field in question, so the prime number limiting the field needs to be at least as large, is this correct ?

Comment: Not quite, for instance if you compute the determinant in F_2, you get a determinant of 7, which isn't in F_2, but 1 = 7 mod 2 is in F_2, and is invertible, so they form a basis in F_2. The bit where you run into trouble is if 7 is actually equal to 0, which happens only in F_7

Comment: @latbbltes That makes sense ! As long as the modulo of the prime number that delimitates the finite field doesn't give zero, there is no conflict. So they intentionally gave us a set of vector whose determinant is equal to a prime number. If the determinant wasn't a prime number, it couldn't reach zero through any modulo obviously because only prime numbers can delimitate a finite field (and so be used as modulo). By saying that 1 is invertible in your example, you mean that there exists a number x such that 1 * x mod 2 = 1 (in this case x = 1 as well), is this correct ?

Comment: @wengen Consider the pair $((2, 0)^\top, (0, 3)^\top)$. The determinant of the matrix produced by adjoining the vectors has determinant $6$, which is not prime, but if $p \in \{2, 3\}$ one of the vectors is zero, so in that case the set is not a basis. In general, the set will fail to be a basis in $\Bbb F_p$ if the determinant of the the matrix is $0$ modulo $p$, i.e., iff $p$ divides the determinant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $n$ column vectors, each with $n$ coordinates, you can form a matrix from them and then the determinant is $0$ if and only if the columns are linearly dependent over the field you're working in. So your next step will be to compute the determinant of a $3\times3$ matrix.

What can go wrong in characteristic $p$? Well, consider a simpler example:

$$ \mathcal{B}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\n\end{pmatrix}\right\}. $$

This will be a basis for $\mathbb{F}^2$ over any field $\mathbb{F}$ where $n\ne0$, but will be linearly dependent if $n=0$. Thus, it will be linearly dependent over any field of characteristic $p$, where $p$ is a prime factor of $n$. (Note it's not about how "large" $n$ or $p$ are relative to each other.)

The determinant in this case is $7$. That means, for instance, over the integers they are linearly independent - there is no "$\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination" which yields the zero vector. However, in the integers mod $7$ for instance, we're basically asking about an integer combination yielding not just the zero vector, but potentially any vector with multiples of $7$ in it (which would be the zero vector mod $7$). So for instance,

$$ 1\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix} +
2\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\2\end{pmatrix} + 
3\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}14\\7\\7 \end{pmatrix} $$

does not tell us our vectors are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Z}$, but it *does* tell us they are linearly dependent mod $7$. (They will be independent in any other characteristic, though.)